# Edit Row in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to update row using Linq below but its not doing update for some reason. I have googled it and can assure that i defenitely have primary key in my table. Below is my code:

```
        public static ReturnedSavedSearchStatus editSavedSearches(Eteach.Objects.SavedSearch savedSearch)
    {
        ReturnedSavedSearchStatus rtn = new ReturnedSavedSearchStatus();
        ET_TBL_TalentpoolSavedSearch dbsavedSearch = new ET_TBL_TalentpoolSavedSearch();
        dbsavedSearch = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ET_TBL_TalentpoolSavedSearch>(savedSearch);

        if (dbsavedSearch.id < 0)
        {
            rtn.status = false;
            rtn.description = "Error: Id cannot be less then 0";

        }
        else
        {

            using (EteachDatabaseDataContext ctx = new EteachDatabaseDataContext())
            {

                var result = ctx.ET_TBL_TalentpoolSavedSearches.SingleOrDefault(s => s.id == dbsavedSearch.id);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    result = dbsavedSearch;
                 //   ctx.ET_TBL_TalentpoolSavedSearches.InsertOnSubmit(dbsavedSearch);
                    ctx.SubmitChanges();

                    rtn.status = true;
                    rtn.description = "Saved Search saved";
                }
            }
        }

        return rtn;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code and see if it even reaches `ctx.SubmitChanges();`?

Comment: yes it does reach ctx.SubmitChanges();

Comment: You need to modify/map the properties of result before calling `SubmitChanges` - you can't assign the whole entity.

Comment: @ Oliver how can I do that, any example please? you mean using AutoMapper?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  The server has an update and an insert command.  You cannot insert an item that already exists and must use update.  Normally I perform an insert and check the number of rows effected (the return value).  If zero rows are returned then the row exists and then I repeat using insert.  Update will give an error if the row does not exist.

Comment: `result.Property1 = dbSavedSearch.Property1;` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in assigning the entire object, that does not change the object content, it changes the memory address of the object instead (you are loosing the object), you should update each property individually like this

```
result.Property1 = dbsavedSearch.Property1;
result.Property2 = dbsavedSearch.Property2;
...
...
ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

Hope this can help you